# The best way to screen print and protect areas?

Tags: print-design, screen-printing

I am fairly new to screen printing, and I am taking on the challenge of screen printing some jerseys for my soccer team.

I have these plain white Nike shirts and I want to screen print a basic pattern onto the front only. The shirt has the sleeves curve into the middle, so I can not just put a rectangle mesh on top of the shirt and print the entire pattern. I also don’t want to print over the Nike logo on the right side. I also want to make sure that the pattern is printed all the way to where the stitching comes together, but not onto the other shirt panels.

How would I be able to use existing techniques to take on this task, is it even possible to accomplish what I am planning, or how can I go about doing this the easiest way? Also, if possible, I would like to use a single mesh if possible and not make multiple for the different sizes.

Below is the shirt I will be using and the yellow highlighted part is where I want to print the pattern. The black rectangle would represent the mesh itself. Obviously adjusted to better fit the entire shirt.
[image]

Comment: In most cases, for shirts with coverage in difficult areas, the *material* is printed *first* as flat material, and *then* the shirts are cut and sewn together. They are not printed *after* a shirt is already made.

Answer (score 3):

In my humble opinion, it is not feasible to do that with screen printing for several reasons.

You would need to unstitch all the shirts first.

Printing a large area needs practice, both the screen and the fabric will stretch on the printed area.

That kind of pattern is ideally printed before any cutting and stitching.

You can not use just any ink. As far as I remember the inks for fabric are thick so they are not absorbed into the fabric.

But a thick ink can potentially limit transpiration and can scrape the skin, especially on the nip area. So do not print anything on that area.

And probably the proper printing method would be sublimation.

It would be a lot better if you take some time to design a confined pattern.

[image]

That has some specific challenges, especially if you do not have experience. Experience also means you have the money to waste on shirts to experiment with.